# Drop down menu question

Tags: 7, views

I found [a tutorial](http://www.only10types.com/2010/12/drupal-collapsible-blog-archive-like.html) for a nice menu for my site.

Everything went well till step 7; when I enter this in Views3 on Drupal 7, I get this error message:

> Display "Block" uses fields but there are none defined for it or all are excluded.

How can I solve this?

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at your "content post date", it seems to be excluded (click at it, uncheck the option "exclude from display") therefore no field is displayed hence the error.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you have selected *Fields* for show format. You have to change show format to *Content* or add some fields under *Fields* section.

Comment: Oke, I don't complete understand you. I have this (http://imagebin.org/181569) as view and this as block (http://imagebin.org/181570). What exactly do I have to change?

Comment: Have a look at your "content post date", it seems to be excluded (click at it, uncheck the option "exclude from display") therefore no field is displayed hence the error.

Comment: roelof, if you find Hamid.N's answer helpful, please vote it up with an up arrow. IN fact do so whenever you find a question or answer helpful. It increases the author's reputation and helps other users find good questions and answers later.  Thanks.

Comment: Hello, The remarks from tostimmi did solve this problem.

Comment: @tostinni You should write your comment as answer.